# How to start activity from a popup window?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a custom popup window with it's own layout in my activity (code that responsible for the work of the popup window is in a separate class PopupWindowActivity). I want to appoint a button in this popup window opening activity. I tried some methods but app crashed with NullPointerException.

The code of this activity is following:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView popupButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.popup_btn);
    likemenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupWindow dw = new PopupWindow(v);
            dw.showLikePopDownMenu();
        }
    });
}

    // my stuff



//popup window
private class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements OnClickListener {
    public PopupWindow(View anchor) {
        super(anchor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        // inflate layout
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) this.anchor.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

        // setup button events
        ImageView aboutButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_about: {
        Intent activity = new Intent(FistActivity.this, About.class);
        startActivity(activity);
        break;
        }

    }
}}
```

}

In another way:

```
private static class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements OnClickListener {
        public PopupWindow(View anchor) {
        super(anchor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        // inflate layout
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) this.anchor.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

        // setup button events
        ImageView searchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
        algebraButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        this.setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_about: {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, About.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
}}
```

eclipse says that at first I should delete `static` from `private static class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements`, then I have following for `intent.setClass(this, About.class);`:

`The method setClass(Context, Class<?>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments 
 (FirstActivity.PopupWindow, Class<About>)`

Please, help.

---

Added log for first crash:

```
03-07 00:28:07.750: D/AndroidRuntime(12472): Shutting down VM
03-07 00:28:07.750: W/dalvikvm(12472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.example.FirstActivity$PopupWindow.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:110)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.quickaction.PopupWindowActivity.<init>(PopupWindowActivity.java:52)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.example.FirstActivity$PopupWindow.<init>(FirstActivity.java:97)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.example.FirstActivity$1.onClick(FirstActivity.java:30)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-07 00:28:07.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If it crashed with a NullPointerException, can you include the stack trace in your question?

Comment: @jbowes I've added log for that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

On button press:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("<your-intent-goes-here");
<context>.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What should I put instead of `"<your-intent-goes-here"`?

Comment: @Sabre The intent you have defined in the intent filter for your activity in the manifest.  In the place of Class put a context that has access to startActivity

Comment: @Sabre In your case it would be PopupWindow.this.startActivity(intent)

Comment: I badly understand English and I still don't understand what I should put instead of "your intent...". But when I put PopupWindow instead of Class eclipse said `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type StartAction.PopupWindow`.

Comment: @Sabre You need a Context Object to call startActivity() from (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)).  Then call the intent that opens the activity you wanted opened... Have you looked over the Dev Guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: I put `Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, About.class);
          startActivity(intent);` and I got error when I tried to open popup window. Please, help me with context.

Comment: @Sabre There really isn't much more I can tell you, this is how you launch an activity exactly. If it is not working you may have a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this.  One would be to pass a reference to your Context via the constructor of the Dialog.